# Page folding effect in iOS appa

Tags: ios, core-animation

How to create the page fold effect like that in Maps and iBooks apps? I think I should use Core Animation but I don't know which Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under iOS5 you can use the new UIPageViewController:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

If you set create a new demo project using Xcode you can choose the template that's based on this controller to see how it works.